# Ошибка access violation at address in module borlndmm.dll write of address

Tags: массивы, c++builder, потоки-данных, структуры

Всем здравствуйте. Не могу побороть ошибку "access violation at address in module borlndmm.dll write of address ". Попробую объяснить. Задача заключается в том, чтобы считать массив структур из файла(Фамилия, Инициалы, Год рождения, Группа, оценка по математики, физики, информатики, химии, и средний бал). И вывести на экран тех учеников, у которых средний бал 4 и выше, и у которых фамилии начинаются на определенную букву. Когда первый раз вписываю букву с которой начинается фамилии все отлично работает, но когда повторно ввожу пишет ошибку "access violation at address in module borlndmm.dll write of address ". Я думаю, это из-за потоков, но вроде все очищаю. Буду благодарен за любую помощь.Заранее спасибо. Пишу на Builder C++.

```
struct SZap{
String fname;
String lname;
int age;
int group;
int fiz,mat,info,him;
double sb;} // сама структура 
 String sta = String(Edit9->Text); 
    char tmp[30];
    int count = 0;
    TStringList *lst = new TStringList;
    lst->LoadFromFile(File_Zap) ;
    String st = lst->Text; // считываю файл в переменную st
    delete lst;
    for(int i=1;i< st.Length();i++) 
    {
            if(st[i] == '\n')
            count++;          // считаю количество строк, чтобы знать какой размерности объявлять массив
    }
    SZap *student = new SZap[count];  // объявляю массив структур
    for(int i = 1;i<=st.Length();i++)
    {
            if(st[i] == '.' && isdigit(st[i+1]) && isdigit(st[i-1])){     
            st[i] = ',';}             // заменяю . на , так как компилятор отказывается воспринимать такие числа 
    } 
   stringstream stl(st.c_str());
   for(int i=1;i<=count;i++)
   {
            stl >> tmp;
            student[i].lname = tmp;
            stl >> tmp;
            student[i].fname = tmp;
            stl >> tmp;
            student[i].age = StrToInt(tmp);
            stl >> tmp;
            student[i].group = StrToInt(tmp);
            stl >> tmp;
            student[i].fiz = StrToInt(tmp);
            stl >> tmp;
            student[i].mat = StrToInt(tmp);
            stl >> tmp;
            student[i].info = StrToInt(tmp);
            stl >> tmp;
            student[i].him = StrToInt(tmp);
            stl >> tmp;
            student[i].sb = StrToFloat(tmp);
    }  // считываю файл в структуру 

    for(int i=1;i<=count;i++){
    if(student[i].sb >= 4)
    {
           if(student[i].lname[1] == sta[1])
           {
            Memo1->Lines->Add(student[i].lname);    // условие задания
           }
    }}
    stl.str("");
    stl.clear();   // всякими способами пытался очистить поток
    delete []student;   
    stl.str(string());
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на ruSO! Проверьте код под отладчиком. Это поможет точнее локализовать проблему. На заметку: [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
  ...
```

Comment: @Alex.jpeg На здоровье. Успехов!